# Seguir sequencia de focus após recarregar a página

Tags: javascript, html, input

Tenho uma página `html`, com vários campos `input`, onde quero passá-los em sequência usando a tecla tab.
Utilizei o `tabindex=""` para seguir a sequência correta.
Porém um desses campos recarrega a página para trazer valores do banco, de acordo com o id inserido.
Preciso que, após recarregar a página, a sequência continue a partir do último campo onde foi inserido valor, mas o que está acontecendo é que o cursor volta para o primeiro `input` da página.
Alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: Poste o código João. Ver o que você já tem, facilita em encontrar uma solução.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar JS para resolver o seu problema.
Ficaria assim:

```js
            $(function(){
                //Declara variável
                var focus_ok;
                //um laço para cada elemento 'input'
                $( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
                    //se o elemento tiver algum valor pega o id dele e armazena
                    if($(this).val()) focus_ok = $(this).attr('id');
                });
                //por algum motivo tive que concatenar o # do id
                focus_ok = "#"+focus_ok;
                //aplica o focus no último id coletado
                $(focus_ok).focus();
            });
```

```css
            form{max-width: 300px;padding: 15px 15px;border:3px solid #9696ff;border-radius: 3px;margin: 5px;font-size: 16px;font-family: Arial;}
            form input{display: block;margin: 5px 0px;margin-bottom: 15px;width: 100%;border: 1px solid #9696ff;padding: 5px 0px;border-radius: 1px;}
            form input:focus{box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
            <label for="">Input 01</label>
            <input type="text" id="input_01" value="input_01">
            <label for="">Input 02</label>
            <input type="text" id="input_02" value="input_02">
            <label for="">Input 03</label>
            <input type="text" id="input_03" value="input_03">
            <label for="">Input 04</label>
            <input type="text" id="input_04">
            <label for="">Input 05</label>
            <input type="text" id="input_05">
        </form>
```